# Material Ui Appbar Customization

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to customize the Appbar for mobile devices but I don't know why I cant't. Somebody,please help me to do that.

here is the appbar for mobile devices. I want to change the background and width:

[image: here is the appbar for mobile devices. I want to change the background and width]

I have shared my full code here with inline styles. By the way I am using material using version 5.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
   Button,
   Menu,
   MenuItem,
   AppBar,
   Box,
   Toolbar,
   IconButton,
   Typography,
   Container,
   Fade,
} from '@mui/material';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
import Link from 'next/link';
import logo from '../../assets/main_logo.png';
import Image from 'next/image';
const Navbar = () = > {
     const[anchorElNav, setAnchorElNav] = React.useState(null);
     const handleOpenNavMenu = (event) = > {
         setAnchorElNav(event.currentTarget);
     };
     const handleCloseNavMenu = () = > {
         setAnchorElNav(null);
     };
     const[anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
     const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
     const handleClick = (event) = > {
         setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
     };
     const handleClose = () = > {
         setAnchorEl(null);
     };
     return ( < AppBar position = 'sticky'
         sx = {
             {
                 backgroundColor: '#000000',
                 opacity: '0.9'
             }
         } >
         <Container maxWidth='xl'>
        <Toolbar disableGutters>
          <Typography
            variant='h6'
            noWrap
            component='a'
            href='/'
            sx={{
              mr: 2,
              display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' },
              fontFamily: 'monospace',
              fontWeight: 700,
              letterSpacing: '.3rem',
              color: 'inherit',
              textDecoration: 'none',
            }}
          >
            <Image src={logo} alt='site_logo' height={40} width={210} />
          </Typography>

          <Box
            sx={{
              flexGrow: 1,
              display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' },
            }}
          >
            <IconButton
              size='large'
              aria-label='account of current user'
              aria-controls='menu-appbar'
              aria-haspopup='true'
              onClick={handleOpenNavMenu}
              color='primary'
            >
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Menu
              id='menu-appbar'
              anchorEl={anchorElNav}
              anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: 'bottom',
                horizontal: 'left',
              }}
              keepMounted
              transformOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'left',
              }}
              open={Boolean(anchorElNav)}
              onClose={handleCloseNavMenu}
            >
              <MenuItem onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}>
                <Typography textAlign='center'>Home</Typography>
              </MenuItem>

              <Typography
                onClick={handleClick}
                onMouseEnter={handleClick}
                onMouseLeave={handleClick}
                textAlign='center'
              >
                Services
              </Typography>

              <MenuItem onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}>
                <Typography textAlign='center'>Projects</Typography>
              </MenuItem>
              <MenuItem onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}>
                <Typography textAlign='center'>Blog</Typography>
              </MenuItem>
              <MenuItem onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}>
                <Typography textAlign='center'>Career</Typography>
              </MenuItem>
              <MenuItem onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}>
                <Typography textAlign='center'>About</Typography>
              </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
          </Box>

          <Typography
            variant='h5'
            noWrap
            component='a'
            href='/'
            sx={{
              mr: 2,
              display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' },
              flexGrow: 1,
              fontFamily: 'monospace',
              fontWeight: 700,
              letterSpacing: '.3rem',
              color: 'inherit',
              textDecoration: 'none',
            }}
          >
            <Image src={logo} alt='site_logo' height={40} width={200} />
          </Typography>
          <Box
            sx={{
              flexGrow: 1,
              display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' },
              margin: '0 2rem',
            }}
          >
            <Button
              onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}
              sx={{
                my: 2,
                color: 'white',
                display: 'block',
                textTransform: 'capitalize',
                fontSize: '1rem',
                padding: '0 1rem',
              }}
            >
              Home
            </Button>
            <Button
              onMouseOver={handleClick}
              sx={{
                my: 2,
                color: 'white',
                display: 'block',
                textTransform: 'capitalize',
                fontSize: '1rem',
                padding: '0 1rem',
              }}
            >
              Services
            </Button>
            <Menu
              id='fade-menu'
              MenuListProps={{
                'aria-labelledby': 'fade-button',
              }}
              anchorEl={anchorEl}
              open={open}
              onClose={handleClose}
              TransitionComponent={Fade}
              sx={{
                display: 'flex',
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                position: 'absolute',
                top: '15',
              }}
            >
              <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Web Development</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>E-Commerce Solution</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Digital Marketing</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Design & Editing</MenuItem>
            </Menu>
            <Button
              onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}
              sx={{
                my: 2,
                color: 'white',
                display: 'block',
                textTransform: 'capitalize',
                fontSize: '1rem',
                padding: '0 1rem',
              }}
            >
              Projects
            </Button>
            <Button
              onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}
              sx={{
                my: 2,
                color: 'white',
                display: 'block',
                textTransform: 'capitalize',
                fontSize: '1rem',
                padding: '0 1rem',
              }}
            >
              Blog
            </Button>
            <Button
              onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}
              sx={{
                my: 2,
                color: 'white',
                display: 'block',
                textTransform: 'capitalize',
                fontSize: '1rem',
                padding: '0 1rem',
              }}
            >
              Career
            </Button>
            <Button
              onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}
              sx={{
                my: 2,
                color: 'white',
                display: 'block',
                textTransform: 'capitalize',
                fontSize: '1rem',
                padding: '0 1rem',
              }}
            >
              About us
            </Button>
          </Box>
          <Button
            fontSize='1rem'
            variant='outlined'
            sx={{ textTransform: 'capitalize' }}
          >
            Contact us
          </Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </Container> < /AppBar>
  );`
};

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: It would be better if you share a working example of your code.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you? What did you mean by working example?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want change the background color and increase the width when it’s on mobile device.

Answer (score 1):

You could use per-breakpoint styling on the AppBar itself.

```
<AppBar
  sx={{
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: { xs: 'green', sm: 'red' },
    width: { xs: 300, sm: 500 }
  }}
/>
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/appbar-change-width-and-color-on-mobile-mjgr30?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I don’t want to change the Appbar, I want to customize the menubar. As you can see in the Image, the menubar has white background and the menuitem is not aligned properly, I want to customize that and I don’t know how to do that.